# Integrate Flutter into an existing project

Tags: android, flutter

I'd like to add Flutter into an existing Android application. The initial projet is really huge so I cannot use `flutter create`, I went on the FAQ but there's a lack of documentation for this.

Here is the exception I get from Gradle :

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:officialGooglePlayStoreDebugCompileClasspath'.
Failed to transform file 'flutter-x86.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
   Transform output file /Users/mch/project/app_flutter/build/app/intermediates/flutter/flutter-x86.jar does not exist.
```

Apparently `flutter-x86.jar` cannot be generated. I tried to copy-paste it from another flutter project but the compilation just fail as well.

Comment: You should link a repo for reproduction. There's far too little informations to know what's wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot link the repo, as it is store on an internal git. But I could link the output of  `flutter run`

Comment: You don't need to link the original project. A new android project would work. As long as it's possible to reproduce the same error

Comment: Here is the full output when running `flutter run -v --debug` : https://pastebin.com/xhuaWyRF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should still run `flutter create` and then swap out the contents of the generated `android` and `ios` folders (via a submodule or whatever) with your existing projects. You will need to then manually port over all the flutter specific gradle tasks and config that are in the template projects to your projects in order for it to work.

You will also need to make sure that you add code to initialize the Flutter application and Plugin Registry, etc.

You will hit a lot of limitations though when trying to add Flutter to an existing app. #1 is that you will only be able to have one Flutter Activity, ViewController, View, etc in an application as a general rule.

It's something that will eventually work really well, and I'm not trying to dissuade you, but just be aware before starting.